# CakePHP: Check if SPECIFIC flash message is set

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a page with several sections with forms that are submitted from the same page. The forms collapse to save space, but I want to conditionally keep them open if there is an error on submission.

In my controller, I set a specific "key" (see `location_key` below) for each form, which allows me to echo them in their respective locations:

In controller:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('You missed something...', 'element_name', array('class'=>'error'), 'location_key');
```

In view:

```
$this->Session->flash('location_key')
```

I'm trying to figure out how to check if `$this->Session->flash('location_key')` exists. If I do this it works but unsets the flash message:

```
if ( $this->Session->flash('location_key') ) // = TRUE
    //Do something
$this->Session->flash('location_key') // = FALSE (because it just got called)
```

How can I test for the presence of this flash message without causing it to go away?

Comment: Have you tried using http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#SessionComponent::check?

Comment: @MartinBean I'm trying to do it with `SessionComponent::check()` and `SessionComponent::read()` but so fall they all return false because I'm not sure what the parameter should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out! This works:

```
$this->Session->check('Message.location_key')
```

It returns true/false depending on whether there are any such flash messages set. `->read()` does the same thing, but returns the flash data if there is (any and crucially, it leaves the session var so it can still be echoed later).

Answer (score 2):

Flash messages are (surprise) [stored in the session](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.1/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SessionComponent.php#L128):

```
public function setFlash($message, $element = 'default', $params = array(), $key = 'flash') {
    CakeSession::write('Message.' . $key, compact('message', 'element', 'params'));
}
```

To test for the presence of a flash message, test for the equivalent key in the session, e.g.:

```
if (CakeSession::check('Message.location_key')) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Woops! I wrote mine at the same time... Thanks!

Comment: Cool - you found a solution =).

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [the api](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-SessionHelper.html#73-152), the SessionHelper returns a string (with the flash message and element) when you do `$this->Session->flash('location_key')`, so why not store that string into a variable?

```
$myFlash = $this->Session->flash('location_key');
if ($myFlash)
   /*etc*/

echo $myFlash;
```

Comment: That'd work, but may not be appropriate and does mean _checking_ for the flash message being set modifies the session permanently.

Comment: True. I just posted a different solution from the ones already posted for someone who might not like having a static string (`"Message."`) coming directly from cake lib (that may or may not change in the future). But I agree with you, your solution "checks" and mine "stores", and in this case checking is best.